# onClickListener() not working on FloatingActionButton and Toolbar Icon

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener, floating-action-button

the onClickListener of my FloatingActionButton and Toolbar Icon are not working.
Here is the code:

```
    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.pausebutton);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EventHandlerClass.releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    });

    search_ico=findViewById(R.id.search_ico);
    search_ico.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,searchActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

It is weird because the "new OnClickListener()" is greyed out like this:
[image: Greyed out]

My clicks are going through the FloatingActionButton, here is the code:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/paused"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:backgroundTint="#38464E"
    app:elevation="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/pausebutton"/>
```

I have absolutely no Idea what is wrong, looks right to me.
Does anyone have some Ideas what I could try?

Comment: In this example the user explicitly casts the findViewById as a Button. Does that help you at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577338/setonclicklistenernew-onclicklistener

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it my own, the problem was that I had this line after the onClickListeners:

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

But this line hast to be right at the top of the OnCreate

Comment: I remember that rarely, when copying and pasting between files from other android projects, the project did not compile ... the code was correct, there were no code errors ... until I saw that I had not placed or deleted the line "setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);" during copy and paste... Good luck in your project

Answer (score 0):

You can click on it and press `option + Enter`. The IDE will tell you it can be replace with lambda
[image]

it can make the code more clear

[image]

Comment: This isn't solving the problem, I still can't click the FloatingActionButton