# How to setOnClickListener to a button inside a ListView that also have the id of the item

Tags: java, android, listview

I am creating an app that tracks the inventory for a shop.
The layout consists of a ListView that has a sale button for each item, and on clicking the sale button, the quantity of the item should be decreased by one and be updated in database.
So my question is how do i set the onClickListener to the button so that it also receives the id of the item for which the sale button was clicked for, as it will enable me to update only the specific item in the database.

Comment: You can set a tag (any Object) to a View. Set the id as tag for the sale Button and retrieve it in the OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

This is an sample example

The Button in the fxml file must have an fx:id so that you can use the button properties in the code behind

it looks like this

```
<Button fx:id="myButton"/>
```

and then you can use it (e.g. in your controller) like that

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO
         }
});
```

please check this also [setOnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577338/setonclicklistenernew-onclicklistener)

Comment: And how do you get access to the data of the row that this button is in?

Comment: There are different ways

Comment: by using a controller for the view and something like this `fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view.fxml"));` and then `ViewController viewController  = fxmlLoader.getController();`

Comment: You then have access to the element in Controller, which is the myButton

Comment: How does that code snippet give the OP access to the sale item's id?

Comment: Hi Rias, thanks for your response, but i still don't know how to get the id of the item for which the item was clicked. For example, when i set OnItemClickListener i will be having the id of the item which is clicked, so i want the same thing but for the sale button